# In my US tax return, Is it required to use 1095 forms for my tax return covering 2015?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

The obamacare website says "Remember 1095-B and C forms are not mandatory until 2016." Does this mean they are only required when I file my tax return for 2016 earnings?

If I need to use information from a form to report health insurance during 2015, what form should I be expecting for proof of coverage of Medicaid?

(I got a job half way through the year and so If I have to use a form to report coverage, I would need one from Medicaid in addition to the form that my employer supplied me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forms 1095B and 1095C will be required for the [2015 tax year](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Health-Care/What-is-Form-1095-B--Health-Coverage/INF27802.html), and are due to you by February 1, 2016 (basically the same deadline as your W-2).

If you're provided minimum essential coverage by a plan (including Medicaid), that plan is required to send you the appropriate form by that date.  Employer sponsored plans, government plans, Marketplace plans, and any other plan all are subject to this requirement.

Contact your insurer or the agency responsible for Medicaid, in order to obtain more information as to when that form will be available and to ensure your address is up to date.

Finally, the IRS has indicated that you do not need to wait for these forms.  Following the advice from [this article](https://www.irs.gov/Affordable-Care-Act/Questions-and-Answers-about-Health-Care-Information-Forms-for-Individuals), you may complete your tax returns without these forms so long as you have other information that proves you have coverage.  You won't be prevented from filing (as you're basically checking a box), so long as you aren't enrolled in a marketplace plan.

Comment: Slightly more precisely, it has to be postmarked to you by Feb 1.  You may receive it later.